# Live activity send a params to react native

Tags: swift, react-native, swiftui

I'm creating a Swift module for an app built in React Native.

I have created a Live Activity view using SwiftUI:

```
struct LiveTripWidget: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
      return ActivityConfiguration(for: LiveTripAttributes.self) { context in
          NotificationView() // Some views
        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
                  // Some views
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
                  // Some views
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
                  // Some views
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
                  // Some views
                }
            }
            compactLeading: {
              // Some views
            } compactTrailing: {
              // Some views
            } minimal: {
              // Some views
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a way to retrieve whether this liveActivity was opened from the `DynamicIsland`, the `compactLeading`, the `compactTrailing`, or the `NotificationView` for each case.

The iOS documentation discusses this topic.

> If you don’t explicitly provide a deep link into your app with
> widgetURL(*:) or Link, the system launches your app and passes a
> NSUserActivity object to the
> scene(*:willContinueUserActivityWithType:) and scene(_:continue:)
> callbacks.

I tried using `widgetURL` or `Link`, but I couldn't see any way to add parameters. On the React Native side, when I print what I receive after clicking on the Live Activity, I get:

```
{"activityType": "NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity", "userInfo": {"WGWidgetUserInfoKeyActivityID": "6C2731F3-D938-4C52-B4B2-79A0E4EFCAF8"}}
```

Therefore, I believe the easiest approach would be to add additional information to the `userInfo` dictionary. However, I'm not sure how to do it or if it's the best approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to add a way to retrieve whether this liveActivity was opened from the DynamicIsland, the compactLeading, the compactTrailing, or the NotificationView for each case"? Do you want to track what the user tapped, or run some function in your app as a result of them being tapped?